# Solve the system (should be easy but I'm a bit forgetful of where to start)

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve this simple system?

$ x + y = -9 $

$ 3x -4y = 43 $

$ 7x - 14y = 147 $

Comment: Try putting the first equation in terms of $x$ or $y$, and putting the result into the second equation.

Comment: Ah,, I get $y = -10$

Comment: Yep! Now put that back into the first equation, you'll get $(x+(-10))=-9$.

Comment: cool $x = 1$, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us solve the system by elimination. Multiply the first equation by $3$ and subtract the second equation from this. (We won't need the third equation for now.) We get the following:
$$3x + 3y = -27$$
$$- ) 3x - 4y = -70$$
$$7y = -70$$
$$\boxed{y = -10}.$$

Substitute this back into one of the equations and get that $\boxed{x = 1}.$ Notice that since the third equation complies with this solution, this is the unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gauss process we get that
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & -9 \\
3 & -4 & 43 \\
7 & -14 & 143 
\end{array} \right) \sim
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & -9 \\
0 & -7 & 70 \\
0 & -21 & 210 
\end{array} \right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & -9 \\
0 & -7 & 70 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right) 
$$
i.e. the third equation is the result of the first two. Thus we need to solve only system of the first two equations.  It's easy to see from the second matrix above that $y = -10$ and thus $x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

multiply all terms in the first by 3 and set it like so

$3x-4y=43$

$3x+3y=-27$

multiply all terms in the bottom equation by -1 and add like terms from the two equations so your final result from that should be:

$-7y=70$

from there you can get x easily